# How to write Ansible Playbook for this cmd => mysql_secure_installation

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

If I run this cmd `mysql_secure_installation` in the Linux terminal, it will be asking for user inputs (y/n/other options).
How to reflect the same in an ansible playbook? I tried out using the shell module for this cmd `mysql_secure_installation` But not sure how to write for user inputs like below.

[My task is to install `MysqlDB` using Ansible Playbook. Also, I have attached my manual steps for **MYSQL Installation**. Please help me with writing an ansible playbook for the same.]

Thanks in advance.

```
#############################################################
Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No: y
Please enter 0 = LOW, 1 = MEDIUM and 2 = STRONG: 1

Please set the password for root here.
New password: <my-password>
Re-enter new password: <my-password>

Do you wish to continue with the password provided?(Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
Remove anonymous users? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
Disallow root login remotely? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : n
Remove test database and access to it? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : n
Reload privilege tables now? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
#############################################################

 MYSQL Installation:--
    
 sudo wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm
 sudo rpm -ivh mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm
 sudo yum install -y mysql-server
 sudo systemctl status mysqld
 sudo systemctl start mysqld
    
 mysql_secure_installation
 .....
 mysql -u root -p
 Enter password: <my-password>
    
 GRANT ALL ON root.* TO root@localhost WITH GRANT OPTION;
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
 exit
 sudo systemctl restart mysqld
 sudo systemctl status mysqld
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: have you checked if role already exist: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/index.html

Comment: Hi @Frenchy... Sorry for saying this .. I'm a newbie to Ansible.. Are you asking me to check any existing role available on ansible-galaxy.. I'm trying to achieve these manual steps (https://www.tecmint.com/install-latest-mysql-on-rhel-centos-and-fedora/) to Ansible Playbook.. 

Please help me on this ..

Comment: dont forget to validate the answer to close your question

Answer (score 0):

yes you have ansible-galaxy to check if role exist, but you have module which already exist too:

a sample to install oracle mysql

```
- name: Install Oracle MySQL repo for RedHat Family.
  yum:
    name: "{{ redhat_mysql_repo }}"
    state: present
  when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat" and 'mysql' in group_names
```

another sample:

```
- name: Initialize MySQL 8.0 Insecure.
  shell: >
       mysqld --initialize-insecure
  when: ('8.0.' in mysql_cli_version.stdout) and (ansible_os_family == "RedHat")
```

you could see the example at [Install MySql_8](https://mydbops.wordpress.com/2019/01/25/automate-mysql-8-0-installation-with-ansible/)